# 'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I've made a form in django and Added Template tag Add_attr the problem is i am getting these error.

```
'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'
```

to

```
{{ form.session_type|add_class='form-control' }}
```

Template tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='add_attr')
def add_attr(value, arg):
return value.as_widget(attrs={'class': arg})
```

editSession.html

```
  <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Session Type</label>
                  <span class="input-icon icon-right">

           {{form.session_type|add_attr:"class=form-control"}}

                  </span>
    </div>
```

views.py

```
class sessionpdate_view(UpdateView):
model = Session
fields = '__all__'
template_name = 'myapp/editSession.html'

success_url = '/sessionDetail/'
```

Comment: `value` us a string, check its type via `type(value)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 'str' object has no attribute 'as\_widget'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895198/django-str-object-has-no-attribute-as-widget)

Comment: I used class base view that solution not work for me